# Flask Permission Denied

Tags: python, html, ubuntu, flask, upload

I am trying to add uploads to my website using flask and ubuntu. The program gives the error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'UploadFile.xlsx', referer
```

whenever I attempt to upload a file. I have given read write and execute to user 33. Any help would be appreciated!

My code:

Python:

```
@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
   return render_template('upload.html')
    
@app.route('/uploader', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
   if request.method == 'POST':
      f = request.files['file']
      f.save(secure_filename(f.filename))
      return 'file uploaded successfully'
```

HTML:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form action = "/uploader" method = "POST" 
         enctype = "multipart/form-data">
         <input type = "file" name = "file" />
         <input type = "submit"/>
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why `33` ? Why not `660` - `rw-rw----` ?

Comment: you could check `print( secure_filename(f.filename) )` to see where it try to save it.

Comment: The flask user in Ubuntu is 33 which I gave those permissions.

Comment: I checked in my Linux and use `www-data` has ID `33`. How do you run it ? Dhdi you check `secure_filename(f.filename)` ? If you run it as `www-data` then it may have different privilages and it may run in different folder then you expect - and then it may not have privilages for this folder. Did you set `app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = ...` ?

Comment: aalways put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I solved the issue... after printing secure file name I realized that I didn't join the file path, Thank you for your help! Also what are these objects (for example) called in python with a string and then a list value??? app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER']

Comment: it is normal dictionary with configuration - ie. `print( app.config.keys() )`, `print( app.config.items() )` and see documentation https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/config/

Comment: you can add your solution as answer. And later you can mark it as accepted and long later you can upvote it - this way you can get more points (reputation score)